# Exception in Application constructor when using JavaFX on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

This is the first thing I've done with JavaFX but I keep getting the same error, even though the code is identical to what I've seen online and in lectures.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        primaryStage.setTitle("My first app");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

It never works because I keep getting this error so I'm not sure if it's something to do with how I added the libraries, even though there are no errors when building the actual class.

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class [packagename].javafx.HelloWorld
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class [packagename].javafx.HelloWorld (in module Javafx_coursework) because module Javafx_coursework does not export uk.ac.reading.fi006677.javafx to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

I removed the package name from the error because it's linked to my university.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does your module-info.java look like?

Comment: @theChoosyBeggar `module Javafx_coursework {
 requires javafx.graphics;
}`

Comment: try including ```exports uk.ac.reading.fi006677.javafx to javafx.graphics;```